# Django pass extra data to ModelSerializer create from a ModelViewSet serializer.save()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this ModelViewSet

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data_to_save = request.data
    pharmacy = Pharmacy.objects.get(pk=request.data['pharmacy'])

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data_to_save)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(myArg=pharmacy)

    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response({'results': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

The `self.get_serializer(...)` points to a `class PharmacyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): ...`

The `PharmacyUserSerializer(...)`, I'm overriding the `create(...)` function like so

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context['request']
    myArg = self.context['myArg']

    pharmacy = request.user.pharmacy
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        **validated_data,
        user_type=c.PHARMACY,
        pharmacy=pharmacy
    )
    return user
```

ACcording to the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save), this line looks right (passing arguments to the save method)

`serializer.save(myArg=pharmacy)`

Doing the above gives the error,

`TypeError: 'myArg' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

So what's going on? What's the right way to pass data (i guess I'm missing something in the docs).

And how do I intercept this extra data in the `PharmacyUserSerializer`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full trace back.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass attribute of your model to serializer in save method not whatever you want. To pass additional variable to your serializer you can use `context`. Check [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) link to how use it.
In your case you should use this code:

```
self.get_serializer(data=data_to_save, context={'myArg': pharmacy})
```

And you already write the code in PharmacyUserSerializer to get `myArg`.